# 'slider angular' Clicking on the small images return the corresponding large images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I used a slide show since site: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-slide-show-plugin-angularjs/

Added small side images . I wonder how do I get when clicking on the small images return the corresponding large images .

Thumbnails added with this code : (place templateurl.html)

```
<ul class="minimage" ng-show="image.visible" >

  <a ng-click="returner()"> <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="/sliderAngular/img/{{image.src}}" width="70" height="56"/> </a>

</ul>
```

This is my attempt , as it could to make it work ?
(place app.js)

```
scope.currentIndex=0;

scope.returner=function(){
   scope.currentIndex= ;

};
```

I'm several days trying unsuccessfully to really need the help of someone who knows . If you need any more information you can ask me, I'm very limited in English and angular.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle/plunker/jsbin to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to leave it the way it wanted a few months ago , now remembered this question and returned to give a more complete answer for future readers.

Place this code below where you want to appear the slider

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div images="images" class="slider" id="mauseOnOut">
    <div  class="slide" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-show="image.visible"> 
        <a ng-href="{{image.url}}"><img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="444" height="250"/>
        <p class="texto">{{image.texto}}</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="minimagem" ng-show="images.length"> 
      <li ng-repeat="image in images"><a ng-click="returner($index)"><img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="70" height="56"/></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="arrows">
        <a href="" ng-click="prev()" ><img  src="http://s5.postimg.org/orczpkx0z/left_arrow.png"/></a> <a href="" ng-click="next()"><img src="http://s5.postimg.org/qkfwdwi7n/right_arrow.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Place the code below into your `app.js` , `controller` or a specific page for `directives`.

```
myApp.directive('images', function factory($timeout) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {

    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'AE',
    multiElement: true,
    scope: {
        images: '='
    },

    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { 
      scope.currentIndex=0;

    scope.returner = function(index){
    scope.currentIndex = index;
   };

        scope.next=function(){
            scope.currentIndex<scope.images.length-1?scope.currentIndex++:scope.currentIndex=0;
        };

        scope.prev=function(){
            scope.currentIndex>0?scope.currentIndex--:scope.currentIndex=scope.images.length-1;
        };

        scope.$watch('currentIndex',function(){
            scope.images. forEach(function(image){
                image.visible=false;
            });
            scope.images[scope.currentIndex].visible=true;
        });

        // Start: For Automatic slideshow

        var timer;

        var sliderFunc=function(){
            timer=$timeout(function(){

                scope.next();
                timer=$timeout(sliderFunc,3000);
            },3000);
        };

        sliderFunc();

        scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
        });

        var myDiv = document.getElementById('mauseOnOut');

        myDiv.onmouseover = function() { 
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
        };

        myDiv.onmouseout = function() { 
            timer=$timeout(sliderFunc,3000);
        };

         // End : For Automatic slideshow
   }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Place the code below into your `controller` and edit as you wish:

```
$scope.images = [

  {
        src:'http://s5.postimg.org/b2wzny14n/img1.png',
        url:'',
        texto:'Trees and mountains a pleasant and peaceful environment to live .'
  },
  {
        src:'http://s5.postimg.org/vlrvt0f1z/img2.jpg',
        url:'',
        texto:'Yellow and pond landscape sky that inspires a reflection on the existence'
  },
  {
        src:'http://s5.postimg.org/wms4i4w1j/img3.jpg',
        url:'',
        texto:'Yellow and pond landscape sky that inspires a reflection on the existence '
  },
  {
        src:'http://s5.postimg.org/k0hplatkn/img4.png',
        url:'',
        texto:'The cold and snow prevents does not prevent good news for those seeking good '
  },
  {
        src:'http://s5.postimg.org/nitphougn/img5.png',
        url:'',
        texto:'Imposing Rhino with your muscles , bones and horns forming one of the strongest animals of nature '
  }
   ];
```

See the CSS and the slider operating in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiagoJem/5t57n/66/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are many things wrong with the code you initially shared, some of which are:

- UL tag doesn't have LI items
- ng-show="image.visible" is outside of the ng-repeat, so image will always be undefined
- the ng-repeat was on the img tag, so there was going to be only 1 link with tons of pictures inside of it.

Code sample using $index (attribute available inside of ng-repeat directives):

```
<ul class="minimage" ng-show="images.length"> <!-- show if there are items  -->
    <li ng-repeat="image in images"><a ng-click="returner($index)"><img ng-src="/sliderAngular/img/{{image.src}}" width="70" height="56"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

And:

```
scope.currentIndex=-1;
scope.returner = function(index){
    scope.currentIndex = index;
};
```

Comment: It worked and was lean the way you did. Only scope.currentIndex is 0 (scope.currentIndex=0;) for the first image appears on the slide.